# Cloud-init script for Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am looking for a way to execute a script at instance launch in Google cloud platform similar to user data in AWS. I check 'Startup script' but it is executed at every boot. is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, accordingly to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) startup script runs on each boot and there's no option available to change this behavior:

> Compute Engine lets you create and run your own startup scripts on
> your virtual machine (VM) instances to perform automated tasks every
> time your instance boots up. Startup scripts can perform actions such
> as installing software, performing updates, turning on services, and
> any other tasks defined in the script.

**To solve this issue** you can use this workaround:

1. Set up a flag, such as a file on the disk, when your startup script runs first time.
2. Check existence of this flag in your startup script and exit without any action if the flag exists.